# Authorization headers taking the previous token value redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux toolkit and i want to send the token to verify if the user is logged in or not so he can like a post.
My code is as follow :

```
const userInfo = localStorage.getItem('userInfo') ?
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) : null

const config = {
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }
}

const auth = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo?.token}`
  }
}

export const likePost = createAsyncThunk("posts/likePost",
      async (id,{ rejectWithValue }) => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.patch(`http://localhost:5000/posts/like/${id}/`,
          config,
          auth,
          id,
        )
        console.log(userInfo?.token)
        return data
      } catch (error) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data)
      }
        
    }
)
```

when i check the headers i find that it takes the token of the previous logged in person

Comment: Where/when do you set the userInfo localStorage item?

Comment: After the user is logged in i store the informations in local storage. When i check the token from the local storage it is for the new logged in user

Comment: More code could help to give an answer but my guess is that your localStorage.getItem is executed before you use localStorage.setItem. Then the localStorage value is stored/cached in redux as the old value.

Comment: localStorage.clear() / localStorage.removeItem(..)  just before setting UserInfo would also help resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes when i log out i clear the local storage then i log in again with the new user

Comment: do you clear the redux state? What happens if you refresh the browser before logging in again?

Comment: @Poku yes i do, same thing

Comment: Ok, out of ideas :) More code would help.

Comment: it works after reloading the page but after logging in with the new user

Comment: i think i solved the problem, but i don't think it is an optimal solution, i had to force to reload the page after the user is logged in

Comment: Have you tried moving `localStorage.getItem()` into the thunk?